# Merge two spark dataframes based on a column

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I have 2 dataframes which I need to merge based on a column (Employee code).  Please note that the dataframe has about 75 columns, so I am providing a sample dataset to get some suggestions/sample solutions.  I am using databricks, and the datasets are read from S3.

Following are my 2 dataframes:

```
DATAFRAME - 1

|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|EMP_CODE   |COLUMN1|COLUMN2|COLUMN3|COLUMN4|COLUMN5|COLUMN6|COLUMN7|COLUMN8|COLUMN9|
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|A10001     |   B   |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------|


DATAFRAME - 2
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|EMP_CODE   |COLUMN1|COLUMN2|COLUMN3|COLUMN4|COLUMN5|COLUMN6|COLUMN7|COLUMN8|COLUMN9|
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|A10001     |       |       |       |       |   C   |       |       |       |       |   
|B10001     |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |T2     |
|A10001     |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |   B   |       |
|A10001     |       |       |   C   |       |       |       |       |       |       |
|C10001     |       |       |       |       |       |   C   |       |       |       |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

I need to merge the 2 dataframes based on EMP_CODE, basically join dataframe1 with dataframe2, based on emp_code.  I am getting duplicate columns when i do a join, and I am looking for some help.

Expected final dataframe:

```
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|EMP_CODE   |COLUMN1|COLUMN2|COLUMN3|COLUMN4|COLUMN5|COLUMN6|COLUMN7|COLUMN8|COLUMN9|
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|A10001     |   B   |       |   C   |       |   C   |       |       |   B   |       |   
|B10001     |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |T2     |
|C10001     |       |       |       |       |       |   C   |       |       |       |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

There are 3 rows with emp_code A10001 in dataframe1, and 1 row in dataframe2.  All data should be merged as one record without any duplicate columns.

Thanks much

Comment: Can I know the reason for downvote? Would appreciate to know the reason for downvote so i can improvise on the question.  Thanks

Comment: You need to use groupBy(EMP_CODE).agg(first("COLUMN1").alias("COLUMN1"),first("COLUMN2").alias("COLUMN2"),......) on dataframe1 or after join to eliminate the duplicates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to aggregate the individual dataframes.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df1 = df1.groupBy('EMP_CODE').agg(F.concat_ws(" ", F.collect_list(df1.COLUMN1)))
```

you have to write this for all columns and for all dataframes.
Then you'll have to use union function on all dataframes.

```
df1.union(df2)
```

and then repeat same aggregation on that union dataframe.

Comment: actually you can skip step 1 by directly doing union all and then you can use that aggregation!

Comment: instead of aggregating, you can tag `.dropDuplicates()` at the end of your union command:
`df1.union(df2).dropDuplicates()`

Answer (score 8):

you can use inner join

```
output = df1.join(df2,['EMP_CODE'],how='inner')
```

also you can apply distinct at the end to remove duplicates.

```
output = df1.join(df2,['EMP_CODE'],how='inner').distinct()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do that in scala if both dataframes have same columns by

```
output = df1.union(df2)
```

Comment: This needs a `.dropDuplicates()` tagged to the end to prevent duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a union.

If both dataframes have the same number of columns and the columns that are to be "union-ed" are positionally the same (as in your example), this will work:

`output = df1.union(df2).dropDuplicates()`

If both dataframes have the same number of columns and the columns that need to be "union-ed" have the same name (as in your example as well), this would be better:

`output = df1.unionByName(df2).dropDuplicates()`