# Can we perform merge/upsert operation between dataframe and table in lakedatabase using pyspark

Tags: sql, pyspark, azure-synapse

I have stored data from storage to sdf dataframe and data from Lake database to another dataframe df and want to perform merge/Upsert. I tried below method still it doesn't seem like working

```
source_path = 'abfss://****.dfs.core.windows.net/***/**.parquet'

df = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM dbo.tablename")

sdf = spark.read.format('parquet').option("recursiveFileLookup", "true").load(source_path)

df.alias("existing").Merge(
source=sdf.alias("updates"),
condition="existing." + key_column + " = updates." + key_column + " and existing." + key_column1 + " = updates." + key_column1).whenMatchedUpdateAll().whenNotMatchedInsertAll().execute()
```

I'm getting

> AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Merge' error

Comment: Please expand on _doesn't seem like working_

Comment: I'm getting - AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Merge' error

Comment: I will edit this into the question for you

Comment: Becuse this is a spark dataframe not a pandas dataframe. People find sample code, which is often pandas, and try and run it in spark. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-spark-dataframe-and-pandas-dataframe/

Comment: "Merge" is too general a term. Do you want to union or join? take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53872107/merge-two-spark-dataframes-based-on-a-column

Answer (score 0):

**Dataframe union()** – `union()` method of the DataFrame is employed to mix two DataFrame’s of an equivalent structure/schema. If schemas aren’t equivalent, it returns a mistake.

I have repro the to merge two sample DataFrames using Union and it is working fine for me.

1. Created two sample dataframes

```
empDF = spark.read.format('csv').options(header='true', inferschema='true').load("/mnt/sampledata2/emp.csv")
depDF = spark.read.format('csv').options(header='true', inferschema='true').load("/mnt/sampledata2/dep.csv")
```

[image]

2. Show the Dataframes

```
empDF.show()
depDF.show()
```

[image]

3. Merge the two Dataframes using union.

```
from functools import reduce  # For Python 3.x
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame
 
def union(*dfs):
    return reduce(DataFrame.unionAll, dfs)
 
mergerdf = union(empDF, depDF)
mergerdf.show()
```

[image]